# In Outlook 365 can I add AutoPick options to Ribbon or QuickAccess toolbar

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I'm creating a meeting in Outlook, so with the Meeting tab active and showing the Scheduling Assistant view ... at the bottom of the screen is a `Options`
drop-down menu\button, in that menu is the `AutoPick` menu which when selected opens a list of selectable options (`All People and Resources`, etc).

I want to expose those so I can just click on them without going through the `Options` menu\button, but when I go to customize I can't find `AutoPick` or any of the options in the commands list (even with show All Commands selected).

Any idea how to find this or expose them so easier to get to?

DF

Office365 ProPlus v 1803

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are in the Meeting view.

Then you may search AutoPick in the "Tell me what you want to do" box, then right click it, choose Add it to QAT:
[image]

You can also using the File > Options > Quick Access Toolbar, but need to ensure you are in the Meeting view:
[image]

Comment: Given the UI in the screenshot above I think we are running two different versions, I have Office 365 ProPlus v 1803 Build 9126.2351.  Adding "AutoPick" to the "Tell me what you want to do" does not find it, so I'm assuming this cmd is just not exposed in my version.  I never knew you could right click in the "Tell me what you want to do" and add to QAT or the Ribbon ... that makes things much easier!

Comment: Sorry for missing the build number in my previous reply. I am in Monthly Channel, Version 1901. If this is an urgent task, you may refer to the steps in the link below to change your update channel and check the result: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sccm/sum/deploy-use/manage-office-365-proplus-updates#change-the-update-channel-after-you-enable-office-365-clients-to-receive-updates-from-configuration-manager